# How can I find out if my user is ZORO

Tags: android, line

I am building app in android, but this is an algorithmic question so everyone can help.

I want somehow to detect when my user draw **Z** latter with their finger.

I been trying to calculate the slope of the user between the last two points and track his changes to know when he start drawing new line. But it is not good enough.

Any ideas how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [GestureBuilder](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/10/gestures-on-android-16.html).

Comment: Or this article: http://www.hascode.com/2010/05/creating-a-simple-gesture-app-with-android/